# A Live CD distro for getting data off a NTFS partition without X Windows

Tags: distributions, data-recovery, livecd, ntfs

The Windows partition on my laptop seems to refuse to boot, and since I lack the original install CD, I was thinking of installing [my preferred Linux distro, Arch](http://www.archlinux.org/) on it.

I want to recover data off the Windows hard drive (and onto my external) first before installing Arch, so I intend to use a Live CD to do so.  Both the Windows HD and my external HD are formatted using NTFS.

However, [the display requires manual configuration in order to use X](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_Inspiron_1525#Video), which precludes the use of a Live CD that will boot directly into X.

What Live CD distros are available that support reading and writing to NTFS (preferably using ntfs-3g) and boot into text mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page).  It boots to a bash shell (where you can startx if you want) and can mount ntfs drives using [ntfs-3g](http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Mounting_an_NTFS_partition_with_full_Read-Write_support).
It also includes a lot of rescue tools.

Comment: They also have a great tutorial just for the purpose asked by @MiffTheFox: http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Backup_data_from_an_unbootable_windows_computer